# CentOS 7 Python ImportError: cannot import name QtWebkit even though it's in my PyQt4 site-packages directory

Tags: python, pyqt4, qtwebkit, ghost, ghost.py

I'm trying to install Ghost.py in CentOS 7.  I've installed the packages below, but it appears that I've missed something, or a path is not available somewhere.  I'm really struggling here, and not sure what I've missed.

```
sudo yum install cmake qconf qt-devel qt4-devel python-devel PyQt4 PyQt4-devel PyQt4-web* xorg-x11-server-ver-Xvfb python-xvfbwrapper
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/qmake-qt4 /usr/bin/qmake
```

Then installed PySide

```
sudo pip install PySide
sudo pip install Ghost.py
```

Then in my interpreter when I go to import it, I get this:

```
Python 2.7.5 (default, Jun 24 2015, 00:41:19) 
[GCC 4.8.3 20140911 (Red Hat 4.8.3-9)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from ghost import Ghost
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ghost/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from .ghost import (
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ghost/ghost.py", line 17, in <module>
    from .bindings import (
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ghost/bindings.py", line 74, in <module>
    QtWebKit = _import('QtWebKit')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ghost/bindings.py", line 41, in _import
    module = __import__(name)
ImportError: No module named QtWebKit
```

I don't understand this, because it's in my `/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/PyQt4` directory:

```
[me@localhost PyQt4]$ ls -lah
total 16M
drwxr-xr-x.  3 root root 4.0K Sep 21 13:56 .
drwxr-xr-x. 43 root root 8.0K Sep 21 13:56 ..
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root 1.1K Jun  9  2014 __init__.py
-rw-r--r--.  2 root root  139 Jun  9  2014 __init__.pyc
-rw-r--r--.  2 root root  139 Jun  9  2014 __init__.pyo
-rwxr-xr-x.  1 root root 406K Jun  9  2014 phonon.so
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root  14K Jun  9  2014 pyqtconfig.py
-rw-r--r--.  2 root root  17K Jun  9  2014 pyqtconfig.pyc
-rw-r--r--.  2 root root  17K Jun  9  2014 pyqtconfig.pyo
-rwxr-xr-x.  1 root root 2.7M Jun  9  2014 QtCore.so
-rwxr-xr-x.  1 root root 236K Jun  9  2014 QtDBus.so
-rwxr-xr-x.  1 root root 267K Jun  9  2014 QtDeclarative.so
-rwxr-xr-x.  1 root root 354K Jun  9  2014 QtDesigner.so
-rwxr-xr-x.  1 root root 8.3M Jun  9  2014 QtGui.so
-rwxr-xr-x.  1 root root 125K Jun  9  2014 QtHelp.so
-rwxr-xr-x.  1 root root 148K Jun  9  2014 QtMultimedia.so
-rwxr-xr-x.  1 root root 771K Jun  9  2014 QtNetwork.so
-rwxr-xr-x.  1 root root 302K Jun  9  2014 QtOpenGL.so
-rwxr-xr-x.  1 root root 218K Jun  9  2014 QtScript.so
-rwxr-xr-x.  1 root root  27K Jun  9  2014 QtScriptTools.so
-rwxr-xr-x.  1 root root 6.8K Jun  9  2014 Qt.so
-rwxr-xr-x.  1 root root 347K Jun  9  2014 QtSql.so
-rwxr-xr-x.  1 root root  99K Jun  9  2014 QtSvg.so
-rwxr-xr-x.  1 root root  36K Jun  9  2014 QtTest.so
-rwxr-xr-x.  1 root root 472K Mar 31  2014 QtWebKit.so
-rwxr-xr-x.  1 root root 179K Jun  9  2014 QtXmlPatterns.so
-rwxr-xr-x.  1 root root 346K Jun  9  2014 QtXml.so
drwxr-xr-x.  6 root root 4.0K Sep 21 13:56 uic
```

Comment: So is `/usr/lib` the same directory as `/usr/lib64`?

Comment: It's not, good catch, and I noticed that last night doing more digging, and didn't want to post here until I figure out what the culprit is.  I'm not sure why pip sometimes installs to `/usr/lib` and then sometimes to `/usr/lib64`.  If I uninstall/reinstall a package, it occasionally will switch.  I can't reproduce it every time.  Not sure why this happens.

Comment: You seem to have two python-2.7 installations. The one in `/usr/lib64` is the system one (i.e. where yum installs packages), whilst the one under `/usr/lib` is one you must have installed yourself. Although the libs are in different directories, the executables are probably both installed in `/usr/bin`. So every time you upgrade/re-install python-2.7, the files in `/usr/bin` (which probably includes `pip`) will get overwritten.

Comment: No, I only have one python install.

Comment: The output from the interpreter session shows that python is trying to import from `/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages`. What is your `$PYTHONPATH`?

Answer (score 0):

PyQt4 is in your site-packages, and that is therefore the package that you have to import. If you specifically want to import QtWebKit from the PyQt4 package, that's what you'll have to do

```
from PyQt4 import QtWebKit
```